# Hibernate attaching object to wrong entity using Spring REST

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-data

So I am trying to save some info to my database in spring using some Seed Data. I am saving by a List and using a debugger on my list object before sending it through my service save method it comes back correctly. After I send it through, one of my objects "Front Office" is incorrectly mapped. But everything else maps correctly.

Here is my Seed Data:

```
    public void generateData()
{

    //region RECORDS
    Record colts17 = new Record();
    colts17.setLosses(6);
    colts17.setWins(3);
    colts17.setSeasonSpan("2017-2018");

    Record colts16 = new Record();
    colts16.setLosses(8);
    colts16.setWins(8);
    colts16.setSeasonSpan("2016-2017");

    List<Record> coltsRecord = new ArrayList<>();
    coltsRecord.add(colts16);
    coltsRecord.add(colts17);

    Record vikings17 = new Record();
    vikings17.setLosses(2);
    vikings17.setWins(6);
    vikings17.setSeasonSpan("2017-2018");

    List<Record> vikingsRecord = new ArrayList<>();
    vikingsRecord.add(vikings17);
    //endregion

    //region FRONT OFFICES
    FrontOffice coltsOffice = new FrontOffice();
    coltsOffice.setGeneralManager("Chris Ballard");
    coltsOffice.setHeadCoach("Chuck Pagano");
    coltsOffice.setOwner("Jim Irsay");

    FrontOffice vikingsOffice = new FrontOffice();
    vikingsOffice.setHeadCoach("Mike Zimmer");
    vikingsOffice.setOwner("Zygi Wilf");
    vikingsOffice.setGeneralManager("Rick Spielman");

    frontOfficeService.saveFrontOffice(coltsOffice);
    frontOfficeService.saveFrontOffice(vikingsOffice);


    //endregionS

    //region PLAYERS

    Player andrewLuck = new Player();
    andrewLuck.setFirstName("Andrew");
    andrewLuck.setLastName("Luck");
    andrewLuck.setPosition("QB");
    andrewLuck.setJerseyNumber(12);
    andrewLuck.setRookieSeason(2012);
    andrewLuck.setLastSeason(2017);
    andrewLuck.setStatus("Active");

    Player malikHooker = new Player();
    malikHooker.setFirstName("Malik");
    malikHooker.setLastName("Hooker");
    malikHooker.setPosition("FS");
    malikHooker.setJerseyNumber(29);
    malikHooker.setRookieSeason(2017);
    malikHooker.setLastSeason(2017);
    malikHooker.setStatus("Active");

    List<Player> coltsPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
    coltsPlayers.add(andrewLuck);
    coltsPlayers.add(malikHooker);

    Player harrisonSmith = new Player();
    harrisonSmith.setFirstName("Harrison");
    harrisonSmith.setLastName("Smith");
    harrisonSmith.setPosition("FS");
    harrisonSmith.setJerseyNumber(22);
    harrisonSmith.setRookieSeason(2012);
    harrisonSmith.setLastSeason(2017);
    harrisonSmith.setStatus("Active");

    Player dalvinCook = new Player();
    dalvinCook.setFirstName("Dalvin");
    dalvinCook.setLastName("Cook");
    dalvinCook.setPosition("RB");
    dalvinCook.setJerseyNumber(33);
    dalvinCook.setRookieSeason(2012);
    dalvinCook.setLastSeason(2012);
    dalvinCook.setStatus("Active");

    List<Player> vikingsPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
    vikingsPlayers.add(harrisonSmith);
    vikingsPlayers.add(dalvinCook);

    //endregion

    //region TEAMS
    Team colts = new Team();
    colts.setHomeTown("Indianapolis");
    colts.setTeamName("Colts");
    colts.setFrontOffice(coltsOffice);
    colts.setPlayerList(coltsPlayers);
    colts.setRecordList(coltsRecord);
    teamService.saveTeam(colts);

    Team cardinals = new Team();
    cardinals.setHomeTown("Arizona");
    cardinals.setTeamName("Cardinals");
    teamService.saveTeam(cardinals);

    Team falcons = new Team();
    falcons.setHomeTown("Atlanta");
    falcons.setTeamName("Falcons");
    teamService.saveTeam(falcons);

    Team ravens = new Team();
    ravens.setHomeTown("Baltimore");
    ravens.setTeamName("Ravens");
    teamService.saveTeam(ravens);

    Team bills = new Team();
    bills.setHomeTown("Buffalo");
    bills.setTeamName("Bills");
    teamService.saveTeam(bills);

    Team panthers = new Team();
    panthers.setHomeTown("Carolina");
    panthers.setTeamName("Panthers");
    teamService.saveTeam(panthers);

    Team bears = new Team();
    bears.setHomeTown("Chicago");
    bears.setTeamName("Bears");
    teamService.saveTeam(bears);

    Team bengals = new Team();
    bengals.setHomeTown("Cincinnati");
    bengals.setTeamName("Bengals");
    teamService.saveTeam(bengals);

    Team browns = new Team();
    browns.setHomeTown("Cleveland");
    browns.setTeamName("Browns");
    teamService.saveTeam(browns);

    Team cowboys = new Team();
    cowboys.setHomeTown("Dallas");
    cowboys.setTeamName("Cowboys");
    teamService.saveTeam(cowboys);

    Team broncos = new Team();
    broncos.setHomeTown("Denver");
    broncos.setTeamName("Broncos");
    teamService.saveTeam(broncos);

    Team lions = new Team();
    lions.setHomeTown("Detroit");
    lions.setTeamName("Lions");
    teamService.saveTeam(lions);

    Team packers = new Team();
    packers.setHomeTown("Green Bay");
    packers.setTeamName("Packers");
    teamService.saveTeam(packers);

    Team texans = new Team();
    texans.setHomeTown("Houston");
    texans.setTeamName("Texans");
    teamService.saveTeam(texans);

    Team jaguars = new Team();
    jaguars.setHomeTown("Jacksonville");
    jaguars.setTeamName("Jaguars");
    teamService.saveTeam(jaguars);

    Team chiefs = new Team();
    chiefs.setHomeTown("Kansas City");
    chiefs.setTeamName("Chiefs");
    teamService.saveTeam(chiefs);

    Team chargers = new Team();
    chargers.setHomeTown("Los Angeles");
    chargers.setTeamName("Chargers");
    teamService.saveTeam(chargers);

    Team rams = new Team();
    rams.setHomeTown("Los Angeles");
    rams.setTeamName("Rams");
    teamService.saveTeam(rams);

    Team dolphins = new Team();
    dolphins.setHomeTown("Miami");
    dolphins.setTeamName("Dolphins");
    teamService.saveTeam(dolphins);

    Team vikings = new Team();
    vikings.setHomeTown("Minnesota");
    vikings.setTeamName("Vikings");
    vikings.setRecordList(vikingsRecord);
    vikings.setPlayerList(vikingsPlayers);
    vikings.setFrontOffice(vikingsOffice);
    teamService.saveTeam(vikings);

    Team patriots = new Team();
    patriots.setHomeTown("New England");
    patriots.setTeamName("Patriots");
    teamService.saveTeam(patriots);

    Team saints = new Team();
    saints.setHomeTown("New Orleans");
    saints.setTeamName("Saints");
    teamService.saveTeam(saints);

    Team giants = new Team();
    giants.setHomeTown("New York");
    giants.setTeamName("Giants");
    teamService.saveTeam(giants);

    Team jets = new Team();
    jets.setHomeTown("New York");
    jets.setTeamName("Jets");
    teamService.saveTeam(jets);

    Team raiders = new Team();
    raiders.setHomeTown("Oakland");
    raiders.setTeamName("Raiders");
    teamService.saveTeam(raiders);

    Team eagles = new Team();
    eagles.setHomeTown("Philadelphia");
    eagles.setTeamName("Eagles");
    teamService.saveTeam(eagles);

    Team steelers = new Team();
    steelers.setHomeTown("Pittsburgh");
    steelers.setTeamName("Steelers");
    teamService.saveTeam(steelers);

    Team fortyNiners = new Team();
    fortyNiners.setHomeTown("San Francisco");
    fortyNiners.setTeamName("49ers");
    teamService.saveTeam(fortyNiners);

    Team seahawks = new Team();
    seahawks.setHomeTown("Seattle");
    seahawks.setTeamName("Seahawks");
    teamService.saveTeam(seahawks);

    Team buccaneers = new Team();
    buccaneers.setHomeTown("Tampa Bay");
    buccaneers.setTeamName("Buccaneers");
    teamService.saveTeam(buccaneers);

    Team titans = new Team();
    titans.setHomeTown("Tennessee");
    titans.setTeamName("Titans");
    teamService.saveTeam(titans);

    Team redskins = new Team();
    redskins.setHomeTown("Washington");
    redskins.setTeamName("Redskins");
    teamService.saveTeam(redskins);

    //endregion

    //region DIVISIONS

    List<Team> afcSouthList = new ArrayList<>();
    afcSouthList.add(colts);
    afcSouthList.add(titans);
    afcSouthList.add(texans);
    afcSouthList.add(jaguars);

    List<Team> afcEastList = new ArrayList<>();
    afcEastList.add(patriots);
    afcEastList.add(jets);
    afcEastList.add(bills);
    afcEastList.add(dolphins);

    List<Team> afcNorthList = new ArrayList<>();
    afcNorthList.add(steelers);
    afcNorthList.add(ravens);
    afcNorthList.add(bengals);
    afcNorthList.add(browns);

    List<Team> afcWestList = new ArrayList<>();
    afcWestList.add(chiefs);
    afcWestList.add(raiders);
    afcWestList.add(chargers);
    afcWestList.add(broncos);

    List<Team> nfcNorthList = new ArrayList<>();
    nfcNorthList.add(vikings);
    nfcNorthList.add(packers);
    nfcNorthList.add(lions);
    nfcNorthList.add(bears);

    List<Team> nfcSouthList = new ArrayList<>();
    nfcSouthList.add(saints);
    nfcSouthList.add(panthers);
    nfcSouthList.add(falcons);
    nfcSouthList.add(buccaneers);

    List<Team> nfcEastList = new ArrayList<>();
    nfcEastList.add(eagles);
    nfcEastList.add(cowboys);
    nfcEastList.add(giants);
    nfcEastList.add(redskins);

    List<Team> nfcWestList = new ArrayList<>();
    nfcWestList.add(rams);
    nfcWestList.add(seahawks);
    nfcWestList.add(cardinals);
    nfcWestList.add(fortyNiners);


    Division afcSouth = new Division();
    afcSouth.setTeamList(afcSouthList);

    Division afcEast = new Division();
    afcEast.setTeamList(afcEastList);

    Division afcNorth = new Division();
    afcNorth.setTeamList(afcNorthList);

    Division afcWest = new Division();
    afcWest.setTeamList(afcWestList);

    List<Division> afcDivisions = new ArrayList<>();
    afcDivisions.add(afcEast);
    afcDivisions.add(afcNorth);
    afcDivisions.add(afcSouth);
    afcDivisions.add(afcWest);

    Division nfcSouth = new Division();
    nfcSouth.setTeamList(nfcSouthList);

    Division nfcEast = new Division();
    nfcEast.setTeamList(nfcEastList);

    Division nfcNorth = new Division();
    nfcNorth.setTeamList(nfcNorthList);

    Division nfcWest = new Division();
    nfcWest.setTeamList(nfcWestList);

    List<Division> nfcDivisions = new ArrayList<>();
    nfcDivisions.add(nfcEast);
    nfcDivisions.add(nfcNorth);
    nfcDivisions.add(nfcSouth);
    nfcDivisions.add(nfcWest);

    divisionService.saveDivisionList(afcDivisions);
    divisionService.saveDivisionList(nfcDivisions);


    //endregion

    //region CONFERENCES
    Conference afc = new Conference();
    afc.setConferenceName("AFC");
    afc.setDivisionList(afcDivisions);


    Conference nfc = new Conference();
    nfc.setConferenceName("NFC");
    nfc.setDivisionList(nfcDivisions);

    List<Conference> conferenceList = new ArrayList<>();
    conferenceList.add(afc);
    conferenceList.add(nfc);

    conferenceService.saveConferenceList(conferenceList);
    //endregion
}
```

Here is my Service Imp, as you can see no custom logic for my save method:

```
@Service
public class FrontOfficeImpl implements FrontOfficeService
{
private final FrontOfficeRepository frontOfficeRepository;

public FrontOfficeImpl(FrontOfficeRepository frontOfficeRepository)
{
    this.frontOfficeRepository = frontOfficeRepository;
}

@Override
public FrontOffice getFrontOfficeById(Integer id) {
    return frontOfficeRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public FrontOffice saveFrontOffice(FrontOffice frontOffice) {
    return frontOfficeRepository.save(frontOffice);
}

@Override
public Iterable<FrontOffice> listAllFrontOffices() {
    return frontOfficeRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Iterable<FrontOffice> saveFrontOfficeList(Iterable<FrontOffice> frontOffices) {
    return frontOfficeRepository.save(frontOffices);
}

@Override
public boolean deleteFrontOffice(Integer id) {
    try
    {
        frontOfficeRepository.delete(id);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the Entity that contains the object incorrectly saving:

```
public class Team
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "TeamId")
private Integer id;

@Version
private Integer version;

private String teamName;

private String homeTown;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "TeamId")
private List<Record> recordList;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TeamId")
private FrontOffice frontOffice;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "TeamId")
private List<Player> playerList;
```

And finally my returning JSON in postman for a team:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Colts",
    "homeTown": "Indianapolis",
    "recordList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "version": 0,
            "wins": 8,
            "losses": 8,
            "ties": 0,
            "seasonSpan": "2016-2017"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "version": 0,
            "wins": 3,
            "losses": 6,
            "ties": 0,
            "seasonSpan": "2017-2018"
        }
    ],
    "frontOffice": {
        "id": 1,
        "version": 0,
        "owner": "Jim Irsay",
        "generalManager": "Chris Ballard",
        "headCoach": "Chuck Pagano"
    },
    "playerList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "version": 0,
            "firstName": "Andrew",
            "lastName": "Luck",
            "position": "QB",
            "rookieSeason": 2012,
            "lastSeason": 2017,
            "jerseyNumber": 12,
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "version": 0,
            "firstName": "Malik",
            "lastName": "Hooker",
            "position": "FS",
            "rookieSeason": 2017,
            "lastSeason": 2017,
            "jerseyNumber": 29,
            "status": "Active"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Cardinals",
    "homeTown": "Arizona",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": {
        "id": 2,
        "version": 0,
        "owner": "Zygi Wilf",
        "generalManager": "Rick Spielman",
        "headCoach": "Mike Zimmer"
    },
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Falcons",
    "homeTown": "Atlanta",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Ravens",
    "homeTown": "Baltimore",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Bills",
    "homeTown": "Buffalo",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Panthers",
    "homeTown": "Carolina",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Bears",
    "homeTown": "Chicago",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Bengals",
    "homeTown": "Cincinnati",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Browns",
    "homeTown": "Cleveland",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Cowboys",
    "homeTown": "Dallas",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 11,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Broncos",
    "homeTown": "Denver",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Lions",
    "homeTown": "Detroit",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 13,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Packers",
    "homeTown": "Green Bay",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 14,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Texans",
    "homeTown": "Houston",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 15,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Jaguars",
    "homeTown": "Jacksonville",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 16,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Chiefs",
    "homeTown": "Kansas City",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Chargers",
    "homeTown": "Los Angeles",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 18,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Rams",
    "homeTown": "Los Angeles",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 19,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Dolphins",
    "homeTown": "Miami",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Vikings",
    "homeTown": "Minnesota",
    "recordList": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "version": 0,
            "wins": 6,
            "losses": 2,
            "ties": 0,
            "seasonSpan": "2017-2018"
        }
    ],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "version": 0,
            "firstName": "Harrison",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "position": "FS",
            "rookieSeason": 2012,
            "lastSeason": 2017,
            "jerseyNumber": 22,
            "status": "Active"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "version": 0,
            "firstName": "Dalvin",
            "lastName": "Cook",
            "position": "RB",
            "rookieSeason": 2012,
            "lastSeason": 2012,
            "jerseyNumber": 33,
            "status": "Active"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 21,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Patriots",
    "homeTown": "New England",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 22,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Saints",
    "homeTown": "New Orleans",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 23,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Giants",
    "homeTown": "New York",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 24,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Jets",
    "homeTown": "New York",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 25,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Raiders",
    "homeTown": "Oakland",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 26,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Eagles",
    "homeTown": "Philadelphia",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 27,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Steelers",
    "homeTown": "Pittsburgh",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 28,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "49ers",
    "homeTown": "San Francisco",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 29,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Seahawks",
    "homeTown": "Seattle",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 30,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Buccaneers",
    "homeTown": "Tampa Bay",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 31,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Titans",
    "homeTown": "Tennessee",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
},
{
    "id": 32,
    "version": 0,
    "teamName": "Redskins",
    "homeTown": "Washington",
    "recordList": [],
    "frontOffice": null,
    "playerList": []
}
]
```

As you can see, the frontOffice Objects are just being persisted to the first 2 team objects for some reason. I have tried messing with some persistence settings and changed from doing all of my saving through a conference, which is a higher level than team. I know it's going to first two because Colts were not the first before and the frontOffice for them was also incorrect and attached to the first object.

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I feel like it's a hibernate issue trying to attach it to the wrong team entity. Any help would be appreciated and if you need anything more let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was in my Team Entity. It was the naming of a @JoinColumn incorrectly. It was only running into an issue with the Front Office because It did not have an associative table created by hibernate.

Here is the solution:

```
public class Team
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "TeamId")
private Integer id;

@Version
private Integer version;

private String teamName;

private String homeTown;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
//@JoinColumn(name = "TeamId")
private List<Record> recordList;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//@JoinColumn(name = "FrontOfficeId")
private FrontOffice frontOffice;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
//@JoinColumn(name = "TeamId")
private List<Player> playerList;
}
```